# Entity framework core says items not found when adding to a property which is a list of reference types

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a `DbContext` class which contains the DbSet:

```
public DbSet<MyRefrenceType> MyRefrenceTypes { get; set; } = null!;
```

The class `MyRefrenceType` has the property:

```
public List<MySecondRefrenceType> MySecondRefrenceTypes { get; set; } = new List<MySecondRefrenceType>();
```

When I do this (`context` is the aforementioned `DbContext`):

```
List<MyRefrenceType> listOfObjects = await context.MyRefrenceTypes.ToListAsync();
MyRefrenceType singleObject = x.First();

singleObject.MySecondRefrenceTypes.AddRange(list of MySecondRefrenceType);
```

I see the following line in `DbContext.ChangeTracker.DebugView.LongView`:

```
MySecondRefrenceTypes: [<not found>, <not found>, <not found>, ...]
```

Then when I call `context.SaveChangesAsync()` I get the following exception:

"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException: 'The database operation was expected to affect 1 row(s), but actually affected 0 row(s);"

Does anyone know why I this is happening?

Comment: It sounds like you're adding a list of null references but it's hard to say for sure because your example is too abstract. Ideally we should be able to copy and paste the code you provide and run it ourselves to see the issue, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). That can be difficult when it involves databases and EF contexts and the like, but we need something a bit more concrete than that. You should check that your child objects actually exist and show us code to prove that they do.

Comment: I realize that my question is very abstract but I'm not sure how give you more information. Also, the list that im adding "list of MySecondRefrenceType" is not null and its objects are not null either.

Comment: Try `await context.MyRefrenceTypes.Include(x => x.MySecondRefrenceTypes).ToListAsync()`